# adding 2 way values to a select in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need help please

I have 2 select box, I want to be able to change one select value and the other one will be calculated and selected

the problem is when I select a value from one select box and the calculation does not exist in the second select box for example if I set the Risk Amount to 700 the investment amount should be 1400 it won't display in the Invest Amount select box

what i want to happen is to display it in the select box but not add it as an option

by the way the select should work both way

please help

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3mCH/

**HTML**

```
Invest Amount:
<select style="width:70px;height:22px;" data-bind="options: AvailableInvestAmount, 
                                                    optionsText: function(item) {
                                                        return '$' + item;
                                                    },
                                                    value: InvestAmount"></select>
<span data-bind="text: InvestAmount"></span>

<br />
<br />

Risk Amount:
<select style="width:70px;height:22px;" data-bind="options: AvailableRiskAmount, 
                                                    optionsText: function(item) {
                                                        return '$' + item;
                                                    },
                                                    value: RiskAmount"></select>
<span data-bind="text: RiskAmount"></span>
```

**ViewModel**

```
var viewModel = {
    RiskAmount: ko.observable(200)
};

viewModel.AvailableInvestAmount = ko.observableArray(['200', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000', '1200', '1500', '2000', '3000', '5000']);
viewModel.AvailableRiskAmount = ko.observableArray(['200', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000', '1200', '1500', '2000', '3000', '5000']);

viewModel.InvestAmount = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return this.RiskAmount() * 2;
    },
    write: function (value) {
        this.RiskAmount(value / 2);
    },
    owner: viewModel
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get i to work using jquery and binding an function instead of a computed binding

http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/Z3mCH/14/

```
var viewModel = {
    RiskAmount: ko.observable(200)
};

viewModel.AvailableInvestAmount = ko.observableArray(['200', '200', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000', '1200', '1500', '2000', '3000', '5000']);
viewModel.AvailableRiskAmount = ko.observableArray(['200', '200', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900', '1000', '1200', '1500', '2000', '3000', '5000']);


viewModel.CalculateInvestAmount = function () {
    var riskAmount = $('#RiskAmount').val();
    var investAmount = riskAmount * 2;
    $('#InvestAmount option:first').val(investAmount).text('$' + investAmount);
    $('#InvestAmount').val(investAmount);

};

viewModel.CalculateRiskAmount = function () {
    var investAmount = $('#InvestAmount').val();
    var riskAmount = investAmount / 2;
    console.log(investAmount);
    console.log(riskAmount);
    $('#RiskAmount option:first').val(riskAmount).text('$' + riskAmount.toFixed(0));
    $('#RiskAmount').val(riskAmount.toFixed(0));
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: An interesting question, glad you got something working - was someone able to help from the forums?

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/RZjPx/

So it seems it's working correctly, but when it calculates, it's trying to find an value (x/2) that doesn't exist in the other list.  So you can see that your example works for values like `1000` where `500` exists in the other list.

Generally, it's a bad idea to update both automatically - it will often end in an endless-loop-like condition.  Instead, you may want to think about performing those calculations on click.  Check out the [awesome] tutorial to [create custom bindings](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings).

Also, my fiddle above shows how a viewModel should be implemented.  While yours may work, it's easier to follow if you implement closer to how the documentation teaches.  I'm still learning KO myself, so my stance may change in the future.

Comment: The way you've implemented the view-model is somewhat odd, I'm working on a new way for you

Comment: thank you any solution is accepted, the fiddle was just a proof of concept but is reflect the actual project

Comment: I realize this isn't anything you didn't already know, but playing around with the options and looking at documentation, it seems that an observable will cause an error if the value is not valid.  You may want to post this to the forum to see if there's a way to check if a value exists

Comment: thanks for trying to help and because you are the only one who tried to help a vote up for you